# Removing Zip Folder Using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, zip, directory

How can i remove or delete a zip folder using php code?

In my application i need to extract a zip folder after extaracting remove the zip folder.
How can i do this?

I can extract or unzip the zipped folder using php code that will successed.
But i dont know hot remove the zipped folder.

This is the code to extract zip folder:

```
$this->load->library('unzip');
$var = $this->unzip->extract('./folder/zip_foldername', './folder/newname');
```

Comment: Once the folder is zipped, it's no longer a folder! This is confusing to some, because some file explorers (like the ones in Microsoft Windows) will display zip files as if they are folders, but they're not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the unlink() function

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Edit: after reading your post again I'm not sure I understood.  Did you mean to delete the zip file or the resulting folder containing all the extracted files?  If the the latter then you would first need to loop through that directory and use unlink to delete all of the files then use rmdir() to delete the directory

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rmdir.php

Comment: i mean that i have a zipped folder in this zipped folder have sub folders and files.I want to delete the zipped folder completely

Comment: You should understand that a zipped folder is actually a file. It does contain the content of a lot of other files, but it's still a file as @toon81 said to you.

Comment: Apparently, some file browsers will allow you to drag a file onto an e-mail window so you can attach it, but then if you drag a zip file onto the window, display a popup saying: "you can't attach a folder to an e-mail message". It's no wonder people get confused!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
unlink('url to zip');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use unlink function in php

```
bool unlink ( string $filename [, resource $context ] )

<?php

unlink('urzipfile.zip');
?>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use CodeIgniter's "standard library", then you could load the [`file` helper](http://www.codeigniter.fr/user_guide/helpers/file_helper.html), then delete the file with `delete_files`.

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('file');
    delete_files('./folder/zip_foldername');
?>
```

Note: I'm using `'./folder/zip_foldername'` since you also used this name in the first parameter of `extract()` which corresponds to the zip file.

If you actually want to delete a whole folder, then just pass `TRUE` to your to `delete_files`.

```
<?php
    $this->load->helper('file');
    delete_files('./folder/newname');
?>
```